# Cant remove my list bulletin style even if its set to none in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a website with Wordpress as CMS, and I installed the "Food and Drink" plugin, and when I put my content via that plugin it creates a list of food( I am doing menu). And now I get bulletin style on my list when I removed it via inspect element(chrome) nothing happened. Here is my code:

```css
.fdm-menu.clearfix, .fdm-menu .clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
.entry-content ol, .entry-content ul {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.entry-content ol, .entry-content p, .entry-content ul, .quote-caption {
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}
.fdm-menu, .fdm-menu>li, .fdm-section, .fdm-section>li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: show the html that applies to, as well. css by itself is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have list-style set to none in base.css, you have this in style.css which overrides it.

```
.entry-content ul > li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Remove it from style.css

Answer (score 0):

You have it listed here as disc so change it to none:

```
 .entry-content ul > li { list-style-type: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `list-style-type` instead of `list-style`